# Using UIPickerView multiple times. iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm a beginner in iOS Objective-C programming so first of all - sorry for being silly.

I'm using UIPickerView to fill UITextField and it works perfectly for the first use.

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiO5t.png)

Lets assume that user made a mistake using pickerview for the first time. He wants to correct this and opens the same pickerview again. Pickerview is empty.

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP6sJ.png)

Also okayButton is missing. What am I doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()


@end

@implementation LoginViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

marksArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
fuelTypeArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
inputArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

marksArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alfa Romeo", @"Aston Martin", @"BMW", @"Cadillac", @"Chevrolet", @"Chrysler", @"Citroen", @"Dacia", @"Daewoo", @"Dodge", @"Ferrari", @"Ford", @"Honda", @"Hummer", @"Hyundai", @"Infiniti", @"Jaguar", @"Jeep", @"Kia", @"Lamborghini", @"Lancia", @"Land Rover", @"Lexus", @"Maserati", @"Mazda", @"Mercedes-Benz", @"Mini", @"Mitsubishi", @"Nissan", @"Opel", @"Peugeot", @"Polonez", @"Pontiac", @"Porshe", @"Renault", @"Rover", @"Saab", @"Seat", @"Skoda", @"Smart", @"Subaru", @"Suzuki", @"Toyota", @"Volkswagen", @"Volvo", nil];

fuelTypeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Benzyna", @"Benzyna+LPG", @"Diesel", @"Elektryczny", @"Hybryda", nil];

okayImageView.hidden = true;
okayButton.hidden= true;

//makes fuelTypePickerView as input console for markTextField
fuelTypePickerView.hidden = true;
fuelTypePickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
fuelTypePickerView.delegate = self;
fuelTypePickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
fuelTypeTextField.inputView = fuelTypePickerView;

//makes markPickerView as input console for markTextField
markPickerView.hidden = true;
markPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
markPickerView.delegate = self;
markPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
markTextField.inputView = markPickerView;


// scrolling login view controller
[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 615)];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
okayImageView.hidden = false;
okayButton.hidden= false;

return 1;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{

if([pickerView isEqual: markPickerView]){
    return 45;
}else if([pickerView isEqual: fuelTypePickerView]){
    return 5;
}else{
    return 0;
}
}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if([pickerView isEqual: markPickerView]){
    self->inputArray = self->marksArray;
    return inputArray[row];
}else if([pickerView isEqual: fuelTypePickerView]){
    self->inputArray = self->fuelTypeArray;
    return inputArray[row];
}else{
    return 0;
}
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row   inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if([pickerView isEqual: markPickerView]){
markTextField.text = [inputArray objectAtIndex:row];
}else if([pickerView isEqual: fuelTypePickerView]){
fuelTypeTextField.text = [inputArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
}

-(IBAction) okayButtonPressed:(id)sender{
if(markPickerView.hidden!=YES){
    okayImageView.hidden = true;
    okayButton.hidden= true;
    markPickerView.hidden=YES;
    [markTextField resignFirstResponder];
}else if(fuelTypePickerView.hidden!=YES){
    okayImageView.hidden = true;
    okayButton.hidden= true;
    fuelTypePickerView.hidden=YES;
    [fuelTypeTextField resignFirstResponder];
}


}



@end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the following lines in your code

```
@interface LoginViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

then in `viewDidLoad`

```
fuelTypeTextField.delegate = self;
markTextField.delegate = self;
```

Now implement **UITextField Delegate** in your **LoginViewController**

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender{ 
    okayImageView.hidden = NO;
    okayButton.hidden = NO; 
    if([sender isEqual:fuelTypeTextField])
    {  
        fuelTypePickerView.hidden = NO;
    }  
    else{  
        markPickerView.hidden = NO;  
    }  
}
```

In your Code after click on OK button you are hiding the PickerView, ImageView and Button. But on next time editing the textField you are not unhiding them thats why they are not shown.